# How can I refactor this XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, refactoring

I have an issue regarding some refactoring of som XSLT code on a project i'm working on. The XSLT I have now

```
<pdf:sometext text="{$metadata/namespace:template 
                     /namespace:template_collection
                     //namespace:option
                     [namespace:identificator 
                      = $report_option_identifier]
                     /namespace:name}"/>
```

The problem is that the XSLT needs to be extended to hit more nodes (a new version of the origianl XML, with slighty changed namespaces and slightly changed tags).

I came up with this code:

```
<xsl:variable name="report_template_collection" 
              select="$metadata
                      /namespace:template
                      /namespace:template_collection 
                      | 
                      $metadata
                      /namespace2:templateV2
                      /namespace2:template_collectionV2" />
<xsl:variable name="current_report_option" 
              select="namespace:option | namespace2:optionV2" />
<xsl:variable name="incomplete_report_option_text" 
              select="$report_template_collection
                      //$current_report_option
                      [namespace:identificator 
                      = $report_option_identifier]
                      /namespace:name"/>

<pdf:sometext text="{$incomplete_report_option_text}"/>
```

But when compiled it comes with ths error:

`Unexpected token '$' in the expression.
$report_template_collection// -->$<-- current_report_option[namespace:opt...`

So my question is: How can I refactor the XSLT to account for the new typs (named V2) and in another namespace. it's important that the same XSLT is compliant to all versions of the XML (both the old and the new version).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is quite unanswerable as it is now. What's the purpose of all those variables? You mention different versions of XML input, but do not show any. I recommend you edit your question and show the following, in this order: 1 sentence explaining what your goal is, what went wrong, a _full_, minimal XSLT stylesheet with your problem present, an XML input - and the XML output you expect.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the value of one of your `select` attributes is not an XPath expression.  Your problem is in the portion of the expression reading ... `//$current_report_option` ... -- since only you know what you were trying to say there, only you can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

An XPath expression of the form `A/B/$C` is actually legal in XPath 2.0, but not in XPath 1.0. But it probably doesn't mean what you think it means. Like @ewh I suspect (without any evidence) that you are imagining that if the variable `$C` is bound to the expression `D|E`, then `A/B/$C` is another way of writing `A/B/(D|E)`. That isn't the case; `$C` is bound to a value (a sequence of nodes), not to an expression.

You could use a function instead of a variable:

```
<xsl:function name="f:current_report_option">
  <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$node/(D|E)"/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:variable name="X" select="A/B/f:current_report_option(.)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference `$current_report_option` in the matter you have done in the xpath expression.  You cannot use XSLT variables like macros, which is what it appears you are trying to do.  The type of `$current_report_option` is a nodeset.

If I interpret your intent correctly on how you are trying to use (incorrectly) `$current_report_option`, you should do something like the following instead:

```
<xsl:variable name="incomplete_report_option_text" 
              select="$report_template_collection
                      //*[self::namespace:option or
                          self::namespace2:optionV2]
                      [namespace:identificator 
                      = $report_option_identifier]
                      /namespace:name"/>
```

I replaced your usage of `$current_report_option` with a node test for checking either old or new option node types.